# TapTargetView not overlaying button

Tags: android, android-library

My tap target view is not overlaying the targeted button.

[image]

**My code:**

```
 new TapTargetSequence(this)
            .targets(
                    TapTarget.forView(findViewById(R.id.button), "Button 1","This is button 1 click").tintTarget(false).targetRadius(100).transparentTarget(false)   ,
                    TapTarget.forView(findViewById(R.id.button2), "Button 2", "This is button 2 click").tintTarget(false),
                    TapTarget.forView(findViewById(R.id.button3), "buttton 3","This is button 3 click").tintTarget(false))
           .start();
```

How can i resolve this issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tap targets are usually for icon sized things. If you want to have your button appear under the tap target, you will need to increase the target radius like you have already and you will need to set `transparentTarget` to `true`.